# Can WebExtensions' command shortcuts be customized?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

[`commands` documentation has `suggested_key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/commands), but doesn't suggest any way for this suggested shortcut to be changed. Is there one? Or is it coming in some future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actively being worked on:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1421811